# How to change vertical indent line color?(Productivity Power Tools 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

My color theme is black, so it isn't easy to see vertical indent line because similar to background color. 
 
How to change vertical indent line color or cannot?

windows10 
Visual Studio 2015 
Productivity Power Tools 2015